# making a picture slider in elm, model updates triggered by loaded element

Tags: elm

I am making a website in elm that includes a dynamic element for browsing pictures. One can click a given thumb to see the full picture in a lightbox, navigate to the next or previous picture or let the picture change automatically every three second.

By default one sees only a small selection (4 thumbs) but it is possible to previews all the thumbs by clicking on "voir toute les photos"

[running example here](http://www.uminokirin.com/FestivalArt.html)

Each user click or tick of the clock change the underlying model, which in turn makes the browser actualize the HTML accordingly.

I am mostly satisfied with the current level of functionality except for the fact than I can't find a way to display a transition screen (or picture) while the next picture is loading.

The lightbox displays the last displayed picture while loading the next one, and transitions abruptly.

Is there a way to trigger a change in the model only when the next picture is loaded?

Or a more idiomatic way to do this sort of thing? I am quite new to elm and web development in general.

the elm code for the gallery is visible at:
https://github.com/eniac314/mairieMurol/blob/master/src/Gallery.elm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a way to know when an image is finally loaded. You can tie into the `img.onload` DOM event, but first you'll need a Json Decoder to pull image `src` attribute out of an event.

Updated to elm-0.18

```elm
onLoadSrc : (String -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg
onLoadSrc tagger =
    on "load" (JD.map tagger targetSrc)

targetSrc : JD.Decoder String
targetSrc =
    JD.at [ "target", "src" ] JD.string
```

Now you can use that decoder to call a new `ImageLoaded String` action, passing the image source as a string.

```elm
img
    [ src imgsrc
    , onLoadSrc ImageLoaded
    ]
    []
```

Look at [demo](https://rofrol.github.io/elm-image-slider) and [code](https://github.com/rofrol/elm-image-slider) (you may need to change the random number in the image url to combat the browser caching the image).

Comment: Great! The onload Dom event is what I needed, and now I see how to use it. Thank you.